# if div contains 'text' remove class

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

Trying to remove my font awesome icon whenever a post has 'Text' in it,
(adding class which removes the content of the class)

### jQuery

```
if ($('.post-content:contains("Text")').length > 0) {
    $(this).find('h3').addClass('removeFa');
}
```

### index.php

```
<div class="filter-website">
    <div class="entry" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $thumb['0'];?>')">
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

### and this is what I add in WordPress

```
<div class="post-content">
    <h3>Blog image</h3>
    <p>Text</p>
</div>
<div class="sep-shadow"></div>
```

### css

```
.removeFa:before, .removeFa:after {
    content: close-quote; 
}
```

Image to show you what I mean:

[image]

I also tried to add a class whenever there is content but that didn't work, but if know a solution for that pls tell me :3 (which I guess would be nice for the loading time since it doesnt have to load content for all the posts instead of adding for a few posts but idk correct me if I am wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you're missing is that the way you're trying to pick up the element to add the class to is incorrect. Instead:

```
$('.post-content:contains("Text") h3').addClass('removeFa');
```

Or more targeted:

```
$('.post-content:has(p:contains("Text")) h3').addClass('removeFa');
```

Example (I added a background to the `.removeFa` class):

```js
$('.post-content:has(p:contains("Text")) h3').addClass("removeFa");
```

```css
.removeFa:before, .removeFa:after {
    content: close-quote; 
}
.removeFa {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-content">
    <h3>Blog image</h3>
    <p>Text</p>
</div>
<div class="sep-shadow"></div>
<div class="post-content">
    <h3>Blog image</h3>
    <p>Not a match</p>
</div>
<div class="sep-shadow"></div>
<div class="post-content">
    <h3>Blog image</h3>
    <p>Text</p>
</div>
<div class="sep-shadow"></div>
<div class="post-content">
    <h3>Blog image</h3>
    <p>Text</p>
</div>
<div class="sep-shadow"></div>
<div class="post-content">
    <h3>Blog image</h3>
    <p>Not a match</p>
</div>
<div class="sep-shadow"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Side note: *Adding* a class to remove a Font Awesome icon seems odd. I'd just remove the `fa` class.

Comment: ayy thx it worked! : ) and ye lol I was really struggling with this filter that I tried so many things lmao kinda fked up everything : p

Answer (score -1):

The following should work. Not sure though, if I understood correctly.

```js
if ($('.post-content').text().is(':empty')){
  $(this).find('h3').addClass('removeFa');
}
```